# How to iterate over results of LINQ where query results using list<> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable

Am fairly new to LINQ and Entity Framework in C# and coming-up short on explanations as to why I can't seem to iterate through the results of a very basic Where command output as a List<>. I have the following method in a class to return the results (I've used generic variable names in my samples, for simplicity):

```
public List<MyTable> GetMyList(int ThisID)
{
    return MyEntities.MyTable.Where(c => c.ForeignKey == ThisID).AsEnumerable().ToList();
}
```

And then in my page code I have the following to call and iterate through the results:

```
List<MyTable> Table1 = GetMyList(1);
Table1.ForEach(delegate(MyTable TableDelegate)
{
    string Value = TableDelegate.Column1
});
```

It all works except for the very important point that the value for "`Column1`" *never changes*. In the example I am working on, I submit the query using a value (as "`ForeignKey`" in the example) that I know to return 3 records, and for those 3 records I know the value for "`Column1`" is different for each one. What I get, however, is 3 instances of the *first record*. I.e., the value for "`Column1`" *doesn't change* as the "ForEach" iterates. I've confirmed that it's iterating properly using breakpoints.

I've tried different methods of structuring the loop, including a normal `foreach` statement, and also a standard `for` statement using the `Count` index of `Table1` as the limit. Same results.

Scratching my head...

Comment: Can you confirm that there is in fact 3 instances of the first row in `Table1` **before** you iterate? Or are they different rows?

Comment: Not sure what that means--sorry... The query in question definitely returns three distinct, different rows when run against the data source (SQL Server) for example.

Comment: What I mean is.. when you're debugging, does your `List<MyTable>` list contain those distinct rows? I'm just checking to see how you're confirming they are distinct. I'm trying to determine whether you're manually querying the database with your own SQL query to confirm the rows are distinct.. or whether you've stepped through your code and the LINQ is definitely returning your distinct rows.

Comment: all you're doing is setting the value of a local variable equal to the  value of Column1 over and over again, that variable never makes it out of that loop. Also, you seem to have a lot of circular complexity here. Maybe explain what you want your end result to be?

Comment: Basically, if I understand you correctly, this shouldn't be happening. What implementation of `ForEach` are you using? Is that custom? I think we're gonna need to see some more code.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: you are correct in that my example code just repeatedly sets a local variable, but that's just for simplicity of the example; I'm actually doing more than that in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured-out what the problem was. It has absolutely nothing to do with the code itself, which is fine. The view from which I have been attempting to query lacked a unique identifier column (a PK column) in the output, as represented in the underlying `.edmx` object. Once I added that in, no problem. The select query now grabs the unique rows. It still seems a little odd to me, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so hopefully this at least helps. I changed some names to make this easier to follow:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    // get records with the id 4
    var myList = GetMyList(4);

    // get the property called Column1 for each one of those records and add them to this list (for demonstration)
    var listOfColumn1 = new List<string>(); // lets assume that column holds a string
    foreach(User usr in myList)
    {
        listOfColumn1.Add(thing);
    }

    // or in a more linq-ish way
    listOfColumn1 = myList.Select(record => record.Column1).ToList();

}

public List<User> GetMyList(int departmentId)
{
    // return a list of users that have the specified department id
    return MyEntities.Users.Where(user => user.DepartmentId== departmentId).ToList();
}


// OR do it in one operation
public void DisplayDepartmentUsers(int departmentId)
{
    MyEntities.Users // from my user table
        .Where(user => user.DepartmentId == departmentId) // get everyone with this department id
        .Select(record => record.Column1) // only select the first column (a string in this case)
        .ToList() // make a list out of the resultant enumerable
        .ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // for each result, run this method (write out to console)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it relates to your problem, but I think it will help you understand LINQ:

```
public List<MyTable> GetMyList(int ThisID)`
{
    return MyEntities.MyTable.Where(c => c.ForeignKey == ThisID).AsEnumerable().ToList();`
}
```

In this example you don't need to use `AsEnumerable`, as all LINQ methods return `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Technically, because this is Entity Framework, it's returning an `IQueryable<T>`, so AsEnumerable is wrapping that. In other words, `AsEnumerable` is preventing any other extension methods from modifying the Database query. So this isn't a one-to-one comparison.